# How to convolve with oneself in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to convolve a keras variable with itself using the tensorflow backend but it throws me an error saying
"ValueError: len(dilation_rate)=2 but should be 0"

the code i'm trying to run is

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

sess = K.get_session()
t = K.variable(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3).astype(np.float32))
convs = K.conv2d(t, t, padding='valid')
a = sess.run(convs)
```

Looking to understand why this doesn't work? And how to get it to work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convolution input must have shape `(BatchSize, width, height, inputChannels)`
A convolution filter must have shape `(width, height, inputChannels, outputChannels)`

So, it would only work if they're shaped like:

```
K.conv2d(K.reshape(t,(-1,3,3,1)), K.reshape(t,(3,3,1,1)))
```